# Page Not Found in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter. I have created bootstrap CMS Site using Codeigniter,This site Also have admin panel.

When I running this on Localhost Its working perfectly.Folder and Sub Folder as well.

localhost link :http://localhost/Parivar/ -- for front end

http://localhost/Parivar/admin/ --- For backend

I have hosted this on Server

My Server link is:http://www.emahapolitician/Parivar/ --- for front end
http://www.emahapolitician/Parivar/admin/ --- for backend

when I running this online first link is running perfectly,but automatically includes index.php file ,But i already removed it from my config.php file.

My .**htaccess** file for  http://www.emahapolitician/Parivar/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|fonts|js|uploads|upload|img|floorplan|mainslider|projectslider|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.emahapolitician.in/Parivar/index.php/$1 [L]
```

My .**htaccess** file for  http://www.emahapolitician/Parivar/admin

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|fonts|js|uploads|upload|img|floorplan|mainslider|projectslider|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.emahapolitician.in/Parivar/admin/index.php/$1 [L]
```

I also removed base_url and index.php file from config.php.

Also admin is subfolder of Parivar and Both Folders are in codeigniter.

When I running this link http://www.emahapolitician/Parivar/admin/
It shows page not found error.
So Please help to resolve this issue

Comment: @kiran-padeshi Are you uses in your code site_url() or base_url() on your link tags. If You had use site_url() then change it to **base_url()**, because site_url() by default add index.php

Comment: I am using base_url()

Comment: Parivar is folder under my emahapolitician.in domain and admin is subfolder in Parivar and both Parivar and admin is in codeigniter framework. Parivar is frntend and admin is backend

Comment: Try to Access directly that means [link](domain_name/front_controller_name/function_name) and [link](domain_name/admin/front_controller_name/function_name) if its accessible than your setting or route or .htaccess has problem. Try to write there any link which is shown in anchor tag(when your first page is accessible)

Comment: And check your server support re-write rule

Comment: is your server a linux server?

Comment: yes my server is linux server

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure your routes.php file under application/config directory. in your routes.php add a route like-

```
$route['Parivar/admin'] = 'the controller where you want to go';
```

then when the server will get this url it will redirect to your desired controller.